# How do you change the default AntiForgeryToken identifier in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Im trying to use AWS Cognito for my auth in a .Net Core MVC-app.

The login works fine, but none of my forms in the views work, they all give an error about my claims not containing "Name"-Claim.

I tried adding the name-claim manually but it still throws errors.

Any ideas how you configure this in .net core?

Error message:

InvalidOperationException: The provided identity of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' is marked IsAuthenticated = true but does not have a value for Name. By default, the antiforgery system requires that all authenticated identities have a unique Name. If it is not possible to provide a unique Name for this identity, consider extending IAntiforgeryAdditionalDataProvider by overriding the DefaultAntiforgeryAdditionalDataProvider or a custom type that can provide some form of unique identifier for the current user.

Startup-config:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                //Sets Default Scheme.
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                //Must match the string for AddOAuth to set OAuth as default Challenge Scheme.
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Cognito";
            })
               .AddCookie()
               .AddOAuth("Cognito", options =>
               {
                   options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"];
                   options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:Secret"];
                   options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/sign-in");
                   options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://myauth.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize";
                   options.TokenEndpoint = "https://myauth.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token";
                   options.SaveTokens = true;
                   options.ClaimsIssuer = "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ID";

                   options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                   {
                        //Adds Cognito id_token to Claims.
                        OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicket
                   };
               });
```

Manually adding name-identifier:

```
private static Task OnCreatingTicket(OAuthCreatingTicketContext context)
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            //Cognito stores user information and Claims in the id_token.
            var idToken = context.TokenResponse.Response["id_token"];
            var jwtToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(idToken.ToString());

            var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtToken.Claims);
            foreach (var item in appIdentity.Claims)
            {
                if (item.Type == "sub")
                { 
                    var name = new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", item.Value);
                    var name2 = new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", item.Value);
                    appIdentity.AddClaim(name);
                    appIdentity.AddClaim(name2);
                break;
                }
            }

            context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Comment: maybe this will help? https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2
also, maybe you just need `add new Claim("Name", item.Value)`

Comment: Tried that too, not sure what its looking for but its not "Name".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the identity you create manually in the `OnCreatingTicket` method is ignored by the antiforgery feature because it's not considered authenticated (see [source on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/dc718f66027e126b3eb6c3aabb0f907b44dc7a7f/src/Antiforgery/src/Internal/DefaultClaimUidExtractor.cs#L40-L91), particularly L51); The reason for this is the `IsAuthenticated` property relies on the `AuthenticationType` property not being `null` or empty (see [source on source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Claims/System/Security/Claims/ClaimsIdentity.cs,273)).

Using the `ClaimsIdentity(IEnumerable<Claim> claims, string authenticationType)` constructor overload should make the antiforgery system take your custom identity into account.

Alternatively, to avoid having to create a custom `ClaimsIdentity` altogether, you could make sure that the one created by the OAuth authentication provider contains one of those claims, which are by default looked for by the [`DefaultClaimUidExtractor`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/dc718f66027e126b3eb6c3aabb0f907b44dc7a7f/src/Antiforgery/src/Internal/DefaultClaimUidExtractor.cs) in the `GetUniqueIdentifierParameters` method:

- `sub`;
- `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`, which is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`; and
- `ClaimTypes.Upn` which is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I Added the claims above to the token and I'm still getting the same error. I noticed I have 2 identities in the Httpcontext.user. The first one only has AuthenticationType set, and the second one has all the claims. Is this as its supposed to be?

Comment: I think you should only have one identity. `context.Principal` already contains an identity, so you should add claims to this one; you'll have to cast `context.Principal.Identity` to `ClaimsIdentity` to be able to add claims to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the name-identifier did not work. After much googleing this is what you need to do:

1. Add the name-identifier to the JWT
2. specify a name for provider in startup:

   ```
   var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtToken.Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
   ```

After step 2 it was resolved.

Full code:

```
    private static Task OnCreatingTicket(OAuthCreatingTicketContext context)
    {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var idToken = context.TokenResponse.Response["id_token"];
        var jwtToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(idToken.ToString());

        var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtToken.Claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi so this seems to be down to the OAuth operation not returning a name 'Claim'.

Basically you can get around this by adding a claim in the '`OnCreatingTicket`' function

So your program will have

```
.AddOAuth("xxx", options =>
{

 ...

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        
        //Adds Cognito id_token to Claims.
        OnCreatingTicket = startup.OnCreatingTicket,
        //OnTicketReceived = 
    };


});
```

and a function - somewhere...

```
public static class startup
    {
        public static Task OnCreatingTicket(OAuthCreatingTicketContext ctx)
        {
            var x = ctx.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault();

            ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "MyName"));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```